# Android - Draw on Canvas made from .gif

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, gif

I have a custom view where normally I was using .png files to draw onto in a canvas and that worked fine but now my requirements are to use .gif files and for some reason the same code will not work. Is there something specific about .gif files that doesnt allow android canvas objects to draw on bitmaps made from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot draw on a canvas created from a .gif file. Once I was able to convert the .gif to .png I was able to draw on the canvas again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can draw GIF files on canvas, but all transparent colours turn into white! I assume it is just a bug, related to the new parameter inPremultiplied in Bitfactory.Options which probably was not tested properly.

I am really frustrated with that, since now I have to replace  GIFs by PNG in all my previous applications. (Fixing the bug in the following version doesn't make any difference, since there will still be models, not supporting GIF transparency.)

Indeed GIF file has it own advantage. It doesn't support alpha or true colour, but it has transparent index which in many cases is what actually needed. If you want PNG files to be not *crucially* bigger in size than GIF (I assume this is the main reason for using GIF instead of PNG), convert PNG files from true color to index (colormap) format (most of graphic editor, including GIMP and Photoshop support that), which works OK with KitKat. You will still lose size, but no mare than 1%.

Comment: I actually read in the android documentation that they dont support the use of gif's. You can use them but the recommend anything else.